# How to gracefully initialize a series of objects in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I need to *temporarily* create an object in format like `one.two.three.four` in my code.

But the way I known to initialize them is annoying. Is there anyway I can gracefully initialize them with *few lines of code*?

What I am doing now is ugly:

```
let one: any;

one = {};

one.two = {};

one.two.three = {};

console.log(one.two.three);
```

Comment: `let one: any = {two: {three: {}}};` if you don't actually care about enforcing any of the types.

Comment: @ggorlen If I need to reuse this format I will create an interface or class, but since its "temporarily", so I don't need to write that many lines of code. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ChrisHeald Oh that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chris suggested, we can simply do it by:

```
let one: any = {two: {three: {four:false}}}
```